# Read a very large text file in Matlab (~30Gb)

Tags: matlab, command, large-files

I have some results in format text include text header. It's about 15-50Gb. I want to import this in Matlab for the treatment. Could you give me some advises what command I should use for this big file?

Comment: Try [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html)

Comment: If you don't have that much RAM (you probably don't), you could also consider using a memory map: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/memory-mapping.html

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20964246/3103767

Comment: Memorymap seems to be the only solution unless you want to fread multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You mat use the Root software that is available at Cern website

This was developed to work with very large files ( say > 1T)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem via `textscan` function. But I had text files around 5 GB. Computer has 16GB RAM and it wasn't enough and have to use `pagefile.sys`. Reading time cca 60min.