# Memory map file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, bigdata

I have decided to use memmapfile because my data (typically 30Gb to 60Gb) is too big to fit in a computer's memory.

My data files consist two columns of data that correspond to the outputs of two sensors and I have them in both .bin and .txt formats.

```
m=memmapfile('G:\E-Stress Research\Data\2013-12-18\LD101_3\EPS/LD101_3.bin','format','int32')
m.data(1)
```

I used the above code to memory map my data to a variable "m" but I have no idea what data format to use (int8', 'int16', 'int32', 'int64','uint8', 'uint16', 'uint32', 'uint64', 'single', and 'double').
In fact I tried all of the data formats listed that MATLAB supports, but when I used the m.data(index number) I never get a pair of numbers (2 columns of data) which is what I expected, also the number will be different depending on the format I used.

If anyone has experience with memmapfile please help me.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rzut4zbrert9fm0/q9SiZYmrdG) are some smaller versions of my data files so people can understand how my data is structured:

cheers
James

Comment: Assuming you have a plain binary file, there is no structure. All the data is simply written in a row, similar to `X(:)` transforming a matrix to a vector. Do you have any information how the binary file is written? If not, try to create small example .txt and .bin files and upload them.

Comment: It appears that using the `'Format'` option you can specify the "array shape".

Comment: @DanielR I don't know how the binary file was written but I have created some relatively small files and uploaded them:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rzut4zbrert9fm0/q9SiZYmrdG

Comment: @A.Donda I think the problem with defining the array shape is that I have two columns of data but of a unknown length; would this still work?

Comment: When using regular data, you can use `reshape(data,2,[])` if the data size is unknown, the `[]` is a placeholder indicating the function to use whatever fits, there probably is a similar option in the 'Format' function

Comment: @Smash Thanks for your comment I used reshape and it did process my data into two columns but the data values are wrong (I compared it by opening that data in a text editor).
I think its because when using memmapfile it automatically formats the data, I also tried all the data types listed in my question to no avail :-/

Comment: The .bin file might have a header on it, or even be compressed.  The file length might give you some clues to header size and datatype: look at a few different files, and compare number of rows with the exact size in bytes.

Comment: You don't necessarily need memmapfile to batch process a large dataset.  You can also use fopen/fread to pull out a small block at a time.  But you still need to know the format...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`memmapfile` is designed for reading binary files, that's why you are having trouble with your text file. The data in there is characters, so you'll have to read them as characters and then parse them into numbers. More on that below.

The binary file appears to contain more than just a stream of floating point values written in binary format. I see identifiers (strings) and other things in the file as well. Your only hope of reading that is to contact the manufacturer of the device that created the binary file and ask them about how to read in such files. There'll probably be an SDK, or at least a description of the format. You might want to look into this as the floating point numbers in your text file might be truncated, i.e., you have lost precision compared to directly reading the binary representation of the floats.

Ok, so how to read your file with `memmapfile`? [This post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101596) provides some hints.

So first we open your file as `'uint8'` (note there is no `'char'` option, so as a workaround we read the content of the file into a datatype of the same size):

```
m = memmapfile('RTL5_57.txt','Format','uint8'); % uint8 is default, you could leave that off
```

We can render the data read in as uint8 as characters by casting it to char:

```
c = char(m.Data(1:19)).' % read the first three lines. NB: transpose just for getting nice output, don't use it in your code
c = 
    0.398516    0.063440
    0.399611    0.063284
    0.398985    0.061253
```

As each line in your file has the same length (2*8 chars for the numbers, 1 tab and 2 chars for newline = 19 chars), we can read `N` lines from the file by reading `N*19` values. So `m.Data(1:19)` gets you the first line, `m.Data(20:38)`, the second line, and `m.Data(20:57)` the second and third lines. Read as much as you want at once.

Then we'll have to parse the read-in data into floating point numbers:

```
f = sscanf(c,'%f')
f =
    0.3985
    0.0634
    0.3996
    0.0633
    0.3990
    0.0613
```

All that's left now is to reshape them into your two column format

```
d = reshape(f,2,[]).'
d =
    0.3985    0.0634
    0.3996    0.0633
    0.3990    0.0613
```

**Easier ways than using `memmapfile`**:
You don't need to use `memmapfile` to solve your problem, and I think it makes things more complicated. You can simply use `fopen` followed by `fread`:

```
fid = fopen('RTL5_57.txt');
c = fread(fid,Nlines*19,'*char');
% now sscanf and reshape as above
% NB: one can read the values the text file directly with f = fscanf(fid,'%f',Nlines*19).
% However, in testing, I have found calling fread followed by sscanf to be faster
% which will make a significant difference when reading such large files.
```

Using this you can read `Nlines` pairs of values at a time, process them and simply call `fread` again to read the next `Nlines`. `fread` remembers where it is in the file (as does `fscanf`), so simply use same call to get next lines. Its thus easy to write a loop to process the whole file, testing with `feof(fid)` if you are at the end of the file.

An even easier way is suggested [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-large-text-files.html): use `textscan`. To slightly adapt their example code:

```
Nlines = 10000;

% describe the format of the data
% for more information, see the textscan reference page
format = '%f\t%f';

fid = fopen('RTL5_57.txt');

while ~feof(fid)
   C = textscan(fid, format, Nlines, 'CollectOutput', true);
   d = C{1};  % immediately clear C at this point if you need the memory! 
   % process d
end

fclose(fid);
```

Note again however that the `fread` followed by `sscanf` will be fastest. Note however that the `fread` method would die as soon as there is one line in the text file that doesn't exactly match your format. `textscan` is forgiving of whitespace changes on the other hand and thus more robust.